# Custom Markers related on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I´m trying make a custom map, but i don´t know if i will need of the
"Google Maps JavaScript API". The situation is as follows:

I need to put several markers in certain places in a particular region
of the map and clicking on any of these markers, it would displays
other related markers (markers children) and hide the other markers
not related to this parent marker.

I thought about creating several maps, a main map that would appear
the parent maps and for each parent marker would show a map with the
parent marker and their

children. I can do it without this API, but i do not know how to click
a parent marker and the children one appear together wiht parent.

I thought about creating a link in the description of each marker that
would target to a "my page" and according parameters of the link I
would display the requested map, but the problem is that This link
generates a blank target and not a self.

Does anyone know what I do, I'm on the right track or should I change
the reasoning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the API.

I think the basic approach would be such:

1. Load all markers into JS arrays or objects so that you can reference them later on, keeping track of parent/child relationships (or you can AJAX-load children in step 3 if necessary).
2. Show all parent markers using `.setMap(yourmap)`.
3. Add a click listener to the parent markers, which will call `.setMap(null)` on all other parents, and call `.setMap(yourmap)` on the parent's children markers.

See:

[API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

[Guide to overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)

Comment: Thanks for help avesse, i hope that be simple as look like and it works well without problem

Comment: Welcome. Update your question with some code if you get it working :)

Comment: i am calculating the hours to develop, for now, if the client will accept, i start to develop!

thanks!